# Access Denied Error when Creating S3 Bucket Policy with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

**Error Summary:**

When attempting to create a bucket policy using CloudFormation, the CREATE_FAILED error occurred with the message "Access Denied." Despite attaching the AmazonS3FullAccess policy to the IAM user and creating a policy specifically allowing the s3:PutBucketPolicy action on the bucket, the access was still denied.

**My Script**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Create an S3 bucket and define bucket policy

Resources:
  FooBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: "foo"
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: "Enabled"
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: "AES256"
      AccessControl: "Private"
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: "ExpireNoncurrentVersions"
            Status: "Enabled"
            NoncurrentVersionExpirationInDays: 365
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "foo"

  S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref FooBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: DenyAccessToRestrictedPrefix
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:PutObject"
            Resource: 
              - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${FooBucket}/bar/*"
          - Sid: AllowWriteAccess
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:PutObject"
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${FooBucket}/*"
```

The error in clouldformation

```
Resource handler returned message: "Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: K6ZKS1J61D9YKD5B, Extended Request ID:foo
```

The error in cloud trail

```
   "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
    "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
    "requestParameters": {
        "bucketPolicy": {
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:PutObject"
                    ],
                    "Resource": [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::foo/bar/*"
                    ],
                    "Effect": "Deny",
                    "Principal": "*",
                    "Sid": "DenyAccessToRestrictedPrefix"
                },
                {
                    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": "*",
                    "Sid": "AllowWriteAccess"
                }
            ]
        },
        "bucketName": "foo",
        "Host": "foo.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "policy": ""
    },
```

I have looked at so many other posts and exhausted all suggestions. I can also verify that i am the user that is deploy the above script to create bucket with bucket policy and my user has the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy attached. I saw a suggestion somewhere that i need the `s3:PutBucketPolicy` that looks like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

So i added that as well.

At this point i really don't know what i am doing wrong i have spent 8 hours with no luck so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using the same underlying user as these AWS credentials, can you save a bucket policy in the S3 console or using the awscli?

Comment: i am deploying the above from awscli , are you suggesting i should try to upload this template directly in console?

Comment: I'm suggesting you try the S3 console or [aws s3pi put-bucket-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-policy.html) just to make sure that your credentials can actually succeed in putting a bucket policy. Take CloudFormation out of the picture for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be saying that you are not permitted to add a Bucket Policy to that new bucket.

This is likely due to your default **S3 Block Public Access** settings that is configured to disallow Bucket Policies to be added to buckets.

To override this default configuration, you will need to add a [AWS::S3::Bucket PublicAccessBlockConfiguration - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-publicaccessblockconfiguration.html) setting in the bucket definition. You will need to set `BlockPublicPolicy` and `RestrictPublicBuckets` to **False** since your Bucket Policy is granting public access to the `foo/` path.

Comment: oh this was it, i wish the error aws surfaces up was a little more explicit now that i know this 403 makes sense but its not obvious at first as the error can be misleading and lead someone towards thinking that the user role they are using does not have the correct permissions etc.